# Google OpenID auth not working on shared host but works on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter along with a module called A3M for authentication users with their Google ID.

Everything works like a breeze on localhost but I am not able to connect to google from my live server.

Can it be because of shared hosting ?

Comment: POssibly. Try to connect to Google using other methods and see if they have a firewall blocking outgoing connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it did not work on shared host was
1. it created some temp files with characters there were not allowed to have on my host
2. SSL was not present
3. it did not get write permission to some directories

It worked fine on a cloud machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a fopen / fread on http://google.com. If that works, dig deeper in the module and see what it uses to access Google.

Comment: I went deep and realized that my framework relies on "PHP-OpenID5.3" library. This library has a module to test which returned me "Unexpected HTTP response.". The issue is likely to be related to fsock or curl api.